# Call function when application loads

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to run a function when application loads in Vue.js ? My code is like below

**main.js**

```
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mounted` or `created` hook in the root instance :

```
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  mounted(){
    //call the function
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

if the called function logic is related to the DOM use `mounted` or `created` if its logic is related to the instance properties.